# ifstream stuck on `\n` when trying to read the previous character

Tags: c++, fstream, interpreter, ifstream, brainfuck

I'm writing a brainfuck interpreter in C++. One of its [language features](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck#:%7E:text=If%20the%20byte%20at%20the%20data%20pointer%20is%20nonzero%2C%20then%20instead%20of%20moving%20the%20instruction%20pointer%20forward%20to%20the%20next%20command%2C%20jump%20it%20back%20to%20the%20command%20after%20the%20matching%20%5B%20command.) is that in a loop if the current byte `!= 0` then go back to the beginning of the loop until it's `== 0`. My approach is reading a file character by character instead of loading the whole file into memory. I use `ifstream::seekg` to go back to the previous character:

```cpp
[[nodiscard]] inline BFInstruction prev_inst()
{
    if (m_file.eof())
        m_file.clear(); // clear eof bit

    m_file.seekg(-2, std::ios::cur); // -1 is the current char so -2 for the previous

    return to_inst(static_cast<char>(m_file.get()));
}
```

It all works until the previous character is a `\n` like in this example:

```
++++++[>++++++++<-
]>>++[>+++++<-]>[<<.+>>-]
```

`m_file.get()` always returns `\n` when the current position is the beginning of a line instead of in this case `-`. How do I fix that?

### UPDATE

Here's a reproducible example:

`main.cpp`

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

char next(std::ifstream &f)
{
    char next;
    do
    {
        next = f.get();
    } while (next == '\n');

    return next;
}

char prev(std::ifstream &f)
{
    f.seekg(-2, f.cur);

    return f.get();
}

int main()
{
    std::ifstream f("../example.txt");

    std::cout << next(f) << '\n'; // `a`
    std::cout << next(f) << '\n'; // `b` (because \n is ignored)
    std::cout << prev(f) << '\n'; // '\n'
    std::cout << prev(f) << '\n'; // `\n` again no matter how many times
                                  // we call `prev()` when we would expect
                                  // `a` to be the previous char

    return 0;
}
```

`example.txt`

```
a
bc
```

Comment: I'm guessing you're using a file with Windows line endings opened in text mode? Seeking isn't reliable in that case. Please show a [mre]

Comment: that's right. I changed my line endings from `CRLF` to `LF` and it worked, but I keep getting the same bug in different places. I'm working on a reproducible example

Comment: Opening your file in binary mode will likely solve some or all of your problems

Comment: will give it a shot

Comment: _Opening your file in binary mode will likely solve some or all of your problems_ But then your code must be prepared to handle CRLF line endings explicitly.

Comment: opening it in binary makes it even worse for `CRLF` line endings

Comment: Your program does not account for `'\r'`, and is doing *seek* in a text file in non-binary mode.

Comment: "My approach is reading a file character by character instead of loading the whole file into memory." Why? And why scan for matching brackets every single time instead of matching them once and saving the matches? And why treat '\n' as a special case different than 'S' or '='?